# Uploading video using the YouTube API via Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to work out how to upload videos to YouTube using the api from flash. There seems to be libraries available for doing this with php, ruby, java etc. but not AS3.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: php, ruby and java - all sounds like server side - use any of them at server and use flash at the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by taking a look at Yahoo's Developer's Guide at:

[Developer's Guide: Data API Protocol – Uploading Videos](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading.html#Browser_based_uploading)

Rey~

Comment: I would then implement a flash form following their HTML suggestion.